# Amazon Product Advertising API Signing Issues

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

i am trying to search in amazon product database with the following code posted in amazon webservice sample codes page

```
AWSECommerceService ecs = new AWSECommerceService();

// Create ItemSearch wrapper
ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
search.AssociateTag = "ABC";
search.AWSAccessKeyId = "XYZ";

// Create a request object
ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();

// Fill request object with request parameters
request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "ItemAttributes" };

// Set SearchIndex and Keywords
request.SearchIndex = "All";
request.Keywords = "The Shawshank Redemption";

// Set the request on the search wrapper
search.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };

try
{
    //Send the request and store the response
    //in response

    ItemSearchResponse response = ecs.ItemSearch(search);
    gvRes.DataSource = response.Items;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    divContent.InnerText = ex.Message;
}
```

and getting the following error

> The request must contain the parameter
>   Signature.

and amazon documentation is not clear about how to sign the requests.

any idea how to make it work???

thx

Comment: check out the documentation here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/RequestAuthenticationArticle.html

Comment: and there's a code sample too: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a helper class for REST called SignedRequestHelper.

You call it like so:

```
SignedRequestHelper helper =
        new SignedRequestHelper(MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY, DESTINATION);
requestUrl = helper.Sign(querystring);
```

There must be a similar one for SOAP calls in the above links.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me where do I get this `SignedRequestHelper` class from? In C#...

Answer (score 3):

i transcribed [this](http://vbguru.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/signing-a-amazon-product-advertising-api-request/) vb code and it works for me

add the service reference and name it Amazon

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl
```

go into the folder where your project is hosted, open the service reference folder and open the Reference.cs, then replace all the occurrences of [][] with [], next open AWSECommerceService.wsdl and find

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ImageSets">
```

and replace with

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageSets">
```

add the following, and you'll need to manually reference some dlls

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using AmazonApiTest.Amazon; //instead of AmazonApiTest use your project name
```

first various interface implementations

```
public class AmazonSigningMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private string accessKeyId = "";
    private string secretKey = "";

    public AmazonSigningMessageInspector(string accessKeyId, string secretKey)
    {
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public Object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel) 
    {
        string operation = Regex.Match(request.Headers.Action, "[^/]+$").ToString();
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        String timestamp = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        String signMe = operation + timestamp;
        Byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signMe);

        Byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
        HMAC hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes);
        Byte[] hashBytes = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(bytesToSign);
        String signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("AWSAccessKeyId", accessKeyId));
        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("Timestamp", timestamp));
        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("Signature", signature));
        return null;
    }

    void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message Message, Object correlationState)
    {
    }
}

public class AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private string accessKeyId = "";
    private string secretKey = "";

    public AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior(string accessKeyId, string secretKey)
    {
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new AmazonSigningMessageInspector(accessKeyId, secretKey));
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatched)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParemeters)
    {
    }
}

public class AmazonHeader : MessageHeader
{
    private string m_name;
    private string value;

    public AmazonHeader(string name, string value)
    {
        this.m_name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
    }
    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return "http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/"; }
    }
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteString(value);
    }
}
```

now you use the generated code in this way

```
ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
search.AssociateTag = "YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG";
search.AWSAccessKeyId = "YOUR AWS ACCESS KEY ID";           
ItemSearchRequest req = new ItemSearchRequest();
req.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "ItemAttributes" };
req.SearchIndex = "Books";
req.Author = "Lansdale";
req.Availability = ItemSearchRequestAvailability.Available;
search.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[]{req};

Amazon.AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient amzwc = new Amazon.AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient();
amzwc.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior("ACCESS KEY", "SECRET KEY"));

ItemSearchResponse resp = amzwc.ItemSearch(search);

foreach (Item item in resp.Items[0].Item)
     Console.WriteLine(item.ItemAttributes.Author[0] + " - " + item.ItemAttributes.Title);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one.. i hope it'll help.. i try and it works.. please share it with others.

download the sample code on http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/Using-WCF-and-SOAP-to-Send-Amazon-Product-Advertising-API-Signed-Requests

we need to update service references, make little change at app.config, program.cs, and reference.cs.

**app.config:
(1.)** appSettings tag; 
  assign accessKeyId and secretKey value,
  add .
**(2.)** behaviours tag -> endpointBehaviors tag -> behaviour tag -> signingBehavior tag;
  assign accessKeyId and secretKey value.
**(3.)** bindings tag -> basicHttpBinding tag; (optional)
  delete binding tag except AWSECommerceServiceBindingNoTransport
  and AWSECommerceServiceBindingTransport.
**(4.)** client tag;
  delete endpoint tag except AWSECommerceServiceBindingTransport.

**program.cs:**
  add itemSearch.AssociateTag = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["associateTag"]; before ItemSearchResponse response = amazonClient.ItemSearch(itemSearch);

**reference.cs:** (open file in service references folder using visual studio)
  **change** private ImageSet[][] imageSetsField; to private ImageSet[] imageSetsField;
  **change** public ImageSet[][] ImageSets {...} to public ImageSet[] ImageSets {...}

finally we can run our program and it will work. good luck..

nb: there will be 1 warning (invalid child element signing behaviour), i think we can ignore it, or if you have any solution please share.. ^^v..