# AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement Amazon Web Services in my project and have run into an unusual block.

I have followed the instructions from the answer given by user3049965 in this question:

[Amazon Product Advertising API Signing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793072/amazon-product-advertising-api-signing-issues)

Everything works, right up until here:

```
Amazon.AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient amzwc = new Amazon.AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient();
```

For whatever reason, Visual Studio is telling me that the namespace for AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient does not exist. Obviously the Amazon namespace is working because things like:

```
ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
```

and

```
ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
```

work perfectly fine. Even

```
AWSECommerceService ecs = new AWSECommerceService();
```

works fine. There are no problems finding those classes. Because of this, I am unable to add my header with the AccessKeyID and SecretKey so no successful calls to the API have been made.

From all the research I have done, AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient should be a valid class and I am stumped as to why it isn't being found. Any help would be appreciated and I can provide any other details that would help narrow down a solution.

Thanks!